# Three.js : Modify the UV of my texture inside a custom ShaderMaterial

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've a plane geometry and I'm creating a CustomShader material related to it. It will receive some textures as uniforms. I'd like the textures to perfectly cover my plane (like the `background-size:cover` css property)

I managed to do it with an utility function when I used my textures with a `MeshBasicMaterial` :

```
cover( texture, aspect ) {

    var imageAspect = texture.image.width / texture.image.height;

    if ( aspect < imageAspect ) {
        texture.matrix.setUvTransform( 0, 0, aspect / imageAspect, 1, 0, 0.5, 0.5 );

    } else {
        texture.matrix.setUvTransform( 0, 0, 1, imageAspect / aspect, 0, 0.5, 0.5 );

    }

}
```

But unfortunately since I'm using the `ShaderMaterial`, my "cover" function doesn't apply anymore. Am I force to do it inside my fragment shader? If so how can I manage to reproduce this behavior ?

Here's my code :

```
const vertexShader = `
    precision highp float;
    uniform mat3 uUvTransform;
    varying vec2 vUv;
    void main() {
        vUv = ( uUvTransform * vec3( uv, 1 ) ).xy;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
}`;

const fragmentShader = `
    precision highp float;
    uniform sampler2D uText1;
    varying vec2 vUv;


    void main() {
        vec2 xy = vUv;

        vec4 color = texture2D(uText1,xy);
        gl_FragColor = color;
}`;
```

And here's my current result :

[image]

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use a custom uniform, e.g. :

```c
uniform sampler2D uText1;
uniform vec2 uUvScale;
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() {
    vec2 uv = (vUv - 0.5) * uUvScale + 0.5;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uText1, uv);
}
```

And :

```js
var imageAspect = texture.image.width / texture.image.height;
if ( aspect < imageAspect ) {
    material.uniforms.uUvScale.value.set(aspect / imageAspect, 1)
} else {
    material.uniforms.uUvScale.value.set(1, imageAspect / aspect)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way Three.js handles texture transformations like `.offset, .repeat, .rotation, .center` is via a Matrix3 that gets passed as a `uniform` into the vertex shader. The vertex shader performs the matrix multiplication, then passes the modified UVs as a varying to the fragment shader.

- You can see that uniform being declared [in the `uv_pars_vertex.glsl.js` file](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/d1a8d3b53104b9da9ee48968cd5a0323e7f0777f/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/uv_pars_vertex.glsl.js)
- You can see the transform being applied in the [`uv_vertex.glsl.js` file](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/d1a8d3b53104b9da9ee48968cd5a0323e7f0777f/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/uv_vertex.glsl.js)

You could copy those lines of GLSL code to your `ShaderMaterial`'s vertex shader, and I think the texture properties will come through in the Matrix3 automatically. However, if for some reason it doesn't, you could recreate the Matrix3 [by copying it from the source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/d1a8d3b53104b9da9ee48968cd5a0323e7f0777f/src/textures/Texture.js#L92) and passing it as a uniform manually. I don't know what your utility function looks like, so it's hard to tell how you're achieving the desired scaling.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanations. On the other hand it was quite difficult to implement compare to soju's solution.

Comment: @Michaël Agreed. Soju's was much easier to follow than all the links I gave you :)